# Verilog non-blocking assignments

Tags: verilog

Consider the following Verilog snippet:

```
module mod1 ( input clk, input [1:0] a, input [1:0] b, output reg [3:0] c); 
 always @ ( posedge clk)
  begin 
    c <= {c, &a, |b};
    c[0] <= ^c[3:2];
  end
endmodule
```

In my textbook it says

> A group of blocking assignments are evaluated in the order they appear in the code, whilst a group of nonblocking assignments are evaluated concurrently, before any of the statements on the left hand sides are updated.

So what does that mean here? Suppose `c = 1100`, `a = 11` and `b = 01` at the beginning.
The first statement will read as `c = 0011` and the second as `c[0] = 0` because the `c` in the second statement is `1100` since the assignments only take effect after the clock cycle if I understood the textbook correctly. But what is `c` in the end? Is it `1100` because of the last statement, or is it `0010`? Please also explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both statements assign a value to `c[0]`, so even with nonblocking assignment, it is the last statement that prevails. This means that `|b` in the first statement is discarded, and the result will be `0010`. The first three bits come from the first statement, and the last bit comes from the second statement, all updated simultaneously.

It could be written as a single, less confusing statement:

```vhdl
c <= {c[1:0], &a, ^c[3:2]};
```