# Doubt in non-blocking regarding order of execution

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, hdl

If I have theses statements:

```
output reg [7:0] cnt;
initial
cnt=8'b00000001;
always @(posedge clk)
begin
cnt<=cnt<<1;
cnt[0]<=cnt[7];
end
```

Now in this how to determine whether bits will get shifted first and then assigned or assigned first and then shifted? Because it will then change either cnt[0] or cnt[1] value depending on which executes first

Comment: Have you tried to simulate this yourself to see what happens? What do you think will happen?

Answer (score 0):

This was already answered in [Are Verilog if blocks executed sequentially or concurrently?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/446990/are-verilog-if-blocks-executed-sequentially-or-concurrently) :

"Statements within an always block are evaluated sequentially, doesn't matter if blocking or non blocking assignments are used - nonblocking assignments are simply deferred assignments, **a subsequent nonblocking assignment to the same reg in the same always block will override the first**" .

So in your code, at time zero you will have cnt = 1 and at all further times you will have cnt = 0.

Comment: But in non-blocking statements the order doesn't matter but in your case answer does depend as you are saying it depends on the order.